# What do the code completion icons mean in R Studio?

Tags: rstudio

The code completion popup menu sometimes shows the same object name with different icons:

[image: R Studio code completion menu]

What do the different icons mean?  I'm using R Studio version 0.99.473.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is a context variable, the second tells you it is a dataframe

You can go to [this support page at RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205273297-Code-Completion) and see all of the possible icons that might come up.

[image: image of icons]

Comment: I was concerned that posting a photograph I do not own from a commercial site was copyright fraud, which is why I linked instead. But that is the image I was referring to when I linked it.